# Setting a Code Igniter session with ajax (Is it possible to set it without using alert?)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/res/createsession/' + $("#language option:selected").data('id') + '/' + $("#language option:selected").data('code'),
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                console.log(response); return;
            }
        });
```

```
    public function index($id, $lang)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata($id . '_lang', $lang);

        echo $this->session->userdata($id.'_lang');
    }
```

is there any way to set the session without using the alert in success?

Answer (score 1):

So yeah it's possible what i did is

```
public function index($id, $lang)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata($id . '_lang', $lang);
    }
```

then removed the alert in response

Comment: Just curious as to why you would think you required to have the alert. An Alert is used for either notification to the user or debug ( for you) . So it's good that you realised you could simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax code is working no need to change.

If not work just use this code

```
$("#selector").change(function(){
   var language = $("#language option:selected").data('id');
   var code = $("#language option:selected").data('code');
   $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('res/createsession)?>" + language + '/' + code,
      method: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
         //alert(response);
         location.reload();
      },
      failure: function(response) {
        console.log(response); return;
      }
   });
});
```

You need to use this controller.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Res extends CI_Controller {
  public function createsession($id, $lang){

     //set session
     $this->session->set_userdata($id . '_lang', $lang);

    //get session. if you want to not get session just remove this code
    echo $this->session->userdata($id.'_lang');

  }
}
?>
```